# Webflux ReadTimeoutHandler returns io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException with null message

Tags: java, netty, spring-webflux

We're using **Webflux Webclient** for making API calls through our spring-webflux application. We've configured ReadTimeout using **io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler** but whenever a ReadTimeout occurs, exception getting raised doesn't contain any message or stacktrace or suppressed exception, due to that it becomes tough to identify the origin of exception.

Exception Snapshot - [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS64h.png)

Our Webclient initializer snippet is as follows -

```
@PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies =
        ExchangeStrategies.builder()
            .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(-1))
            .build();

    HttpClient httpClient =
        HttpClient.create()
            .tcpConfiguration(
                client ->
                    client
                        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10000)
                        .doOnConnected(
                            conn ->
                                conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(1))
                                    .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(1))));
    ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient.wiretap(true));
    webClient =
        builder
            .baseUrl(appConfig.getBaseUrl())
            .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
            .clientConnector(connector)
            .build();
  }
```

**Maven Dependencies** -

- spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: the cause of a ReadTimeoutException is a read timeout. What else do you think/are considering could be the origin of the exception?

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen expecting the stacktrace to come up just like any other exception